# what is the working of arr[arr1,arr2] in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, data-science

Recently I came across a code snippet. Please explain to me it's working.

```
arr = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
a1 = np.array([[1,2],[0,1]])
a2 = np.array([[0,2],[1,2]])

#please explain this line 
out = arr[a1,a2]

print(out.sum())
```

Comment: See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

```
arr = [[0 1 2]
       [3 4 5]
       [6 7 8]]

arr[a1, a2] = [ [arr[a1[0,0], a2[0,0]] arr[a1[0,1], a2[0,1]]] ]
                [arr[a1[1,0], a2[1,0]] arr[a1[1,1], a2[1,1]]] ]
            = [ [arr[1,0] arr[2,2]] ]
                [arr[0,1] arr[1,2]] ]

out = [[3 8]
      [1 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of:

`arr[i,:]` selects i-th row and all the columns.

`arr[:,i]` selects i-th column and all the rows.

`arr[i,j]` selects i-th row and j-th column.

Let's say `i` or `j` are vectors- For example take `i = [[a,b]]`. Now, `arr[i,:] = arr[[a,b],:]` will select a-th and b-th rows.

So, if:

```
arr = [[0 1 2],
       [3 4 5],
       [6 7 8]]

a1 = [[1,2],
     [0,1]]

a2 = [[0,2],
     [1,2]]
```

you can think of `arr[a1,a2]` in the following way:

- Select row 1 and column 0 => `3`
- Select row 2 and column 2 => `8`
- Select row 0 and column 1 => `1`
- Select row 1 and column 2 => `5`